# SQL: Verify if date is between two dates

Tags: sql

How can i check if an date value equals a date within the summer period.

I'd expect it to be something like:

```
SELECT Row WHERE Orderdate BETWEEN '01/01/%' AND '31/08/%'
```

However i'm not allowed to use wildcards in a BETWEEN Clause, right?

/edit

That works, thanks both u guys! i'm sorry i can only pick one correct answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: in (standard) SQL that would **not** be "*syntactically allowed*" if `orderdate` was a `DATE` column (even if I ignore the fact that it does not contain a `from` clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm not allowed to use wildcards in a BETWEEN, right?

No but you could do this:

```
SELECT Row WHERE MONTH(Orderdate) BETWEEN 1 AND 8
```

Note that adding an index on `MONTH(Orderdate)` will significantly speed up this query since otherwise it will have to do an INDEX SCAN or TABLE SCAN.

Comment: Although your anwser is correct i am getting back results that are not between the specific months i enter. Any idea's?

Comment: Do you have sample inputs and results?

Answer (score 1):

You want the "summer" (undefined) period.  Most SQL databases would allow you to do:

```
WHERE month(Orderdate) in (6, 7, 8)
```

Otherwise, you can use `extract(month from OrderDate) in (6, 7, 8))`.

This assumes that the month period is defined as June, July, and August.  And, there are many other database-specific solutions.